# Errors when trying to install libc6

Tags: package-management

I was trying to install libc6 with this commend:  sudo apt-get install libc6*

and I got some errors:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcgi-application-plugin-captcha-perl : Depends: libdata-random-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libcloog-isl-dev : Conflicts: libcloog-ppl-dev but 0.16.1-5 is to be installed
 libclutter-gst-2.0-doc : Conflicts: libclutter-gst-doc but 1.6.0-2build1 is to be installed
 libcuda1-304 : Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
 libcuda1-304-updates : Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
 libcuda1-331 : Breaks: libcuda-5.0-1
                Breaks: libcuda-5.5-1
 libcuda1-331-updates : Breaks: libcuda-5.0-1
                        Breaks: libcuda-5.5-1
 libcunit1-ncurses : Conflicts: libcunit1 but 2.1-2.dfsg-1 is to be installed
 libcunit1-ncurses-dev : Conflicts: libcunit1-dev but 2.1-2.dfsg-1 is to be installed
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-nss-dev but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: libcurl4-openssl-dev but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libcurl4-nss-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libcurl4-openssl-dev but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                        Conflicts: libcurl4-nss-dev but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Someone help me plz :/

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was trying to install libc6 with this commend: sudo apt-get install libc6*

Using `libc6*` there is selecting many more packages than you probably intended.

From the [apt-get man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the database.

So `libc6*` means "every package that contains `libc`". There are bound to be some conflicts there.

You can try `sudo apt-get install '^libc6.*'` to get just packages that start with `libc6`, but that's going to get you a *lot* of packages meant for other architectures (for cross compilation).

You may be fine with `sudo apt-get install libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev`, if you just want all the typical libc6 packages for your architecture. I imagine your system already has `libc6` installed.

Comment: tnx but actually im trying to install steam on 64bit system and i get this error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6/ have any any idea to fix ?:/  / with sudo apt-get install libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev it says everything is installed and updated

Comment: You can install the 32-bit version by typing `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`.

Comment: ow ! the sudo apt-get install '^libc6.*'  worked well :) tnx bro